# GMAP.net Route stroke middle cap

Tags: c#, maps, gmap.net

How to add route with stroke Middle Cap(Arrow) on map in gmap.net ----->---- something like this?
currently I wrote this

```
List<PointLatLng> routeItems = new List<PointLatLng>();
routeItems.Add(previousPosition);
routeItems.Add(curposition);

GMapRoute myroute = new GMapRoute(routeItems, "route" + position.Id);
AdjustableArrowCap bigArrow = new AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5, false);
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
p.DashStyle = DashStyle.DashDot;
bigArrow.MiddleInset = 5;
p.CustomStartCap = bigArrow;
myroute.Stroke = p;
last10markerOverlay.Routes.Add(myroute);
```

Comment: Post what code you have already tried. We need to know you have done your homework.

Comment: Does that mean you don't know?

Answer (score -1):

You could simply add the route and then use the mid point of the coordinates of the route to position a custom marker by deriving from `GMapMarker` as shown [in the samples](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Demo.WindowsForms/CustomMarkers/GMarkerArrow.cs).

Basically override the `OnRender(Graphics g)` method and do the custom drawing in there.

Comment: The link is not valid.

Comment: The response is 8 years old. Sorry, but I'm not aware of where this project is hosted by now. ;)